# in 'for loops and range', although same range, two result differs. wanna know why

Tags: python

I'm currently learning python, and I found my self encountered some issue.

```
a={}
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in str(i):
        a[i]='%sth number'%(j)
b={}
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        b[i]='%sth number'%(j)

print(a)
print(b)
```

anyone could tell why does this two are different?

Comment: The range is **clearly** not the same `∀i: str(i) != range(0,10)`, so I wonder what you find surprising about this.

Comment: .... what? Those are absolutely not equivalent.

Comment: what is difference between str(i) and range(0,10)?

Comment: I thought that str(i) would change from 0 to 9...

Comment: @MosesKoledoye you are a mathematician too!?

Comment: 0 to 9...since the range command is working from 0 till n-1

Comment: you can even remove the 0 getting the same values

Comment: @e4c5 I pretend to be one, every now and then :)

Comment: Where is the output? Why don't you show us?

Comment: a->{0:'0th number', 1:'1th number', ....... 9:'9th number'}
b->{0:'9th number', 1:'9th number' ........9:'9th number'}

Comment: @임정묵 would you mind accepting the answer you found most useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case you are going for each element only once inside and you are looking at the version of your number as a string.

In the second case for each number from 0 to 9 you are going again from 0 till 9 and the LAST case will overwrite all the precedence (thus you are getting always 9th)

In particularly replying your query, you can add an additional if cause:

```
if i == j: as below. In your second case I will explain a bit more:

i=1....then j=1; b[1] =1th
still i=1...then j=2; b[1] = 2th
still i=1...then j=3; b[1] = 3th
still...
....
....
still i=1...then LAST j=9; b[1] = 9th

now you are going into i=2:
i=2....then j=1; b[2] =1th
still i=2...then j=2; b[2] = 2th
still i=2...then j=3; b[2] = 3th
still...
....
....
still i=2...then LAST j=9; b[2] = 9th
```

And same will happen for all the i :-) Is it now clear?
Hope this clarify your query.

```
a={}
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in str(i):
        a[i]='%sth number'%(j)
b={}
for i in range(0,10):
    for j in range(0,10):
        if i == j:
            b[i]='%sth number'%(j)

print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: actually I'm sorry but I don't understand why number 9 would be overwritten in case2.....
is there a way that i could get same result while saving 'for j in range(0,10):'??

Comment: @임정묵 please check my updated answer..this will help your understanding :) Have a nice day!

Comment: Welcome!Nice day to you!!

Answer (score 1):

`str(i)` merely casts the integer `i` to a string. So doing `for j in str(i):` runs through *every character* in `i` as a string... which is only 1, in each case you've provided.

It would not run through all the numbers 0-9 as a string because you are casting each *individual integer* to a string as it is generated by the loop. If you put all the characters into a string first, *then* ran the second for loop through them, you might see the same results as the other loop.

Comment: Oh I think I got it!

'for j in str(i): ' is meaningless loop condition because it is same as j=i.
did i got that right?

Comment: Sort of. I wouldn't say *the same* exactly, and it's not a *useless* loop condition but it certainly doesn't do what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### Why are these two different?

well `str` and `range` have completely different functionality.

#### str()

`str(any_value)` will simple convert `any_value` to a string `"any_value"`

eg: `str(1) = "1"`, `str(23.5) = "23.5"`

#### range()

`range(integer_value)` will create a list from `0` to `intger_value - 1`

eg: `range(5)` = `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

**coming back to your question, in the first scenario your second loop won't go through a list of number, rather than an string representation of the number.** Your inner loop is executed only 1 time on every outer loop iteration.

**However in the second scenario you are actually traversing through a list of numbers generated by range()**. Your inner loop is executed 9 times on every iteration of the outer loop.

Hope this helps :)
You can read more about [str](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) and [range](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) here.